# how to create dependent select using backpack-for-laravel?

Tags: laravel-backpack

How to create a **dependent select** like country / city relationship using **backpack-for-laravel**?
Like: just show cities for the selected country

```
    $this->crud->addField([  // Select2
        'label' => "country",
        'type' => 'select2',
        'name' => 'country_id', // the db column for the foreign key
        'entity' => 'country', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'country', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App\Models\Country" // foreign key model
     ]);

    $this->crud->addField([  // Select2
        'label' => "City",
        'type' => 'select2',
        'name' => 'city_id', // the db column for the foreign key
        'entity' => 'city', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'city', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App\Models\City" // foreign key model
     ]);
```

Comment: It's been a while, but did you resolve this problem? I have the same problem. Posted it today. Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468799/laravel-backpack-select-dependent-from-another-select

Comment: Are there any solution for this for the version as of 4.1? I'm also needing to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature for that, but is not merged yet. You may take a look at [[Feature][3.4][Ready] Select2_from_ajax can depend on any other input](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/1484) and check it out the modified files and reproduce in your installation.