# Laravel - Backpack select dependent from another select

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-backpack

I recently installed `Laravel Backpack` admin in my Laravel project. Currently right now I'm working on it. But I need help. So...

**What I want:**

I want to have two selects, first one is `Category` and the second one is `Article`. So `Article` select must depend on `Category` select. And `Article` `belongsTo` `Category`.

**Category-Article**

```
Category 1 = [ Article 1, Article 2, Article 3 ]
Category 2 = [ Article 4, Article 5 ]
```

This is just a showing of which article belongs to category. So for example, when I click `Category 1` on `category` select, on `article` select it should show me only `Article 1, Article 2 and Article 3`.

**What I did**

I followed instructions on Backpack docs, for `Add a select2 field that depends on another field` on this [link](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-how-to#add-a-select2-field-that-depends-on-another-field). So what I did first:

I created two tables, `Category` table and `Article` table. Their models:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    // protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['title'];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FUNCTIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public function articles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article');
    }
}
```

This is a `Category` model, and this is `Article` model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    // protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'category_id'];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FUNCTIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

I made relationships between these two models like this. So when I create `Article` it shows me title and I have to choose `category_id` from `category select`.

After all this I made `Archive` table and these are my migrations:

```
Schema::create('archives', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('title');

   $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

   $table->bigInteger('article_id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');

   $table->timestamps();
});
```

And my `Archive.php` model:

```
class Archive extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'archives';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    // protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'category', 'article'];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FUNCTIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

    public function article(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Article');
    }
}
```

And then I followed instructions from the `backpack docs`. 
This is my `ArchiveCrudController`:

```
public function setup()
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CrudPanel Basic Information
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Archive');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/archive');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('archive', 'archives');

        $this->crud->setColumns(['title', 'category', 'article']);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => "Archive title"
        ]);

        $this->crud->addField([    // SELECT2
            'label'         => 'Category',
            'type'          => 'select',
            'name'          => 'category_id',
            'entity'        => 'category',
            'attribute'     => 'title',
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([ // select2_from_ajax: 1-n relationship
            'label'                => "Article", // Table column heading
            'type'                 => 'select2_from_ajax',
            'name'                 => 'article_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
            'entity'               => 'article', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute'            => 'title', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'data_source'          => url('api/article'), // url to controller search function (with /{id} should return model)
            'placeholder'          => 'Select an article', // placeholder for the select
            'minimum_input_length' => 0, // minimum characters to type before querying results
            'dependencies'         => ['category'], // when a dependency changes, this select2 is reset to null
            //'method'                    => ‘GET’, // optional - HTTP method to use for the AJAX call (GET, POST)
        ]);


        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CrudPanel Configuration
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        // TODO: remove setFromDb() and manually define Fields and Columns
        //$this->crud->setFromDb();

        // add asterisk for fields that are required in ArchiveRequest
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(StoreRequest::class, 'create');
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(UpdateRequest::class, 'edit');
    }
```

Like from `backpack docs`. Then I made `Api` folder in `App\Http\Controller` and then I made `ArticleController` in it, like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search_term = $request->input('q');
        $form = collect($request->input('form'))->pluck('value', 'name');

        $options = Article::query();

        // if no category has been selected, show no options
        if (! $form['category']) {
            return [];
        }

        // if a category has been selected, only show articles in that category
        if ($form['category']) {
            $options = $options->where('category_id', $form['category']);
        }

        if ($search_term) {
            $results = $options->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_term.'%')->paginate(10);
        } else {
            $results = $options->paginate(10);
        }

        return $options->paginate(10);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return Article::find($id);
    }
}
```

I just copy-paste code from `docs` but of course I changed model for my need. 
And finally my `routes`:

```
Route::get('api/article', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ArticleController@index');
Route::get('api/article/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ArticleController@show');
```

I copy-paste these routes in my `web.php` in `routes` folder and in `custom.php` in `routes/backpack` folder.

But when I choose category in my `Archive create` no `articles` showing. 
Can someone please help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From backpack 4.1 you should include 'include_all_form_fields' => true attribute on the dependent field.

Answer (score 0):

you have some issue in your code i hope this would solve them:

1- in ArchiveCrudController: be sure that the dependencies with category_id not category ...

```
'dependencies'         => ['category_id'], 

 $this->crud->addField([ // select2_from_ajax: 1-n relationship
            'label'                => "Article", 
            'type'                 => 'select2_from_ajax',
            'name'                 => 'article_id',
            'entity'               => 'article',
            'attribute'            => 'title', 
            'data_source'          => url('api/article'), 
            'placeholder'          => 'Select an article',
            'minimum_input_length' => 0, querying results
            'dependencies'         => ['category_id'], 
            //'method'                    => ‘GET’,
        ]);
```

2- in Archive Model $fillable should take db column names not relations ...

```
 protected $fillable = ['title', 'category_id', 'article_id'];
```

3- also when you get $form request parameter, it comes with name category_id like you name it in Crud not (category)

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search_term = $request->input('q');
        $form = collect($request->input('form'))->pluck('value', 'name');

        $options = Article::query();

        // if no category has been selected, show no options
        if (! $form['category_id']) {
            return [];
        }

        // if a category has been selected, only show articles in that category
        if ($form['category_id']) {
            $options = $options->where('category_id', $form['category_id']);
        }

        if ($search_term) {
            $results = $options->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_term.'%')->paginate(10);
        } else {
            $results = $options->paginate(10);
        }

        return $options->paginate(10);
    }
```